# networking on VirtualBox suddenly stopped working

Tags: linux, networking, windows-10, wireless-networking, virtualbox

I am using several Linux guest in VirtualBox on a windows 10 laptop.

A week ago the networking in all 6 Linux guests in VirtualBox stopped working. These Linux distros include Debian and Ubuntu variations.

I have a similar setup on my desktop which still works fine.

I compared all the network setting on both computer and they are the same, but on the desktop I have full network access, but on the laptop I can ping 8.8.8.8 but not www.google.com.

I have un-installed VirtualBox and reinstalled, Version 5.1.18 for windows, 3 times on the laptop with no change.

My laptop is a Toshiba Satellite P50t with 16Gb ram and 1Tb SSD hard drive.

I was using Wifi, but I have just connected to Ethernet cable with no change.

I have tried adding nameserver 8.8.4.4 and 8.8.8.8 to resolv.conf with no effect.

Luc

Comment: I had exactly the same problem, so I would like to add one more symptom: Remote desktop to a running VM stops working, even from the host (on localhost).
Otherwise thanks to jseguillon, the solution worked for me as well.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check if a program named "Lavasoft companion" is installed ? This "tool" works for some days but after a period it fails with "CERT_E_EXPIRED" error in your VBoxHardening.log.

You can search for LavasoftTcpService64.dll in your Windows\System32\ directory.

If installed : follow this procedure https://www.adaware.com/forum/index.php?/topic/34376-solution-for-lavasofttcpservice-problem-after-uninstallation/

Comment: Hi jseguillon, That was the problem. as soon as I removed Lavasoft Web Companion, everything works again. That Lavasoft is a pest. Thank you so much for finding this. I spent many hours trying to get this working  again.

Comment: You should outline, quote, and cite the procedure within the body of your answer.

Comment: Hi, What I did to remove Lavasoft Web Companion is: un-install it. the nremoved the Lavasoft...dll fines from both the System32 and sysWOW64 directories found under the Windows directories on drive C:. in those same directories I also removed some Lavasoft..ini files.

Comment: Donwvoted why ? This solution clearly helped OP to get NAT working again... I wish i had this solution when I got myself in trouble; it would have saved me from 2 full days of troubleshooting...